# SQL query for getting the value ,based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I need a help to get one sql Query. I have one  table 'EMP' .

```
id  name    mid
1   A       1
2   B       1
3   C       2
4   D       1
5   E       2
```

I want the result as

```
id  name    mid
1   A       A
2   B       A
3   C       B
4   D       A
5   E       B
```

can any one help me to do this.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  If you have tried a query, please include it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple self join:

```
select id, t1.name, t2.name from emp t1 join emp t2 on t1.mid=t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

using inner join:

```
select EMP1.id, EMP1.name, EMP2.name AS MID from EMP AS EMP1 INNER JOIN EMP AS EMP2 on EMP1.mid=EMP2.id
ORDER BY EMP1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside [@alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38309497/1666800) answer you can also try these two too:

**Method 1**

```
SELECT T.Id ,T.Name ,D.Name AS mid
FROM EMP AS D
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Id ,Name FROM EMP AS T WHERE mid = D.id) AS T;
```

**Method 2**

```
SELECT Id ,Name ,(SELECT Name FROM EMP WHERE id = T.mid) AS mid
FROM EMP AS T;
```